# How to set value of label in windowOpened event of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, windowlistener

I have a JLabel into JFrame, I want in windowOpened event of JFrame set label to 'Hello Java' but i get following error :

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

code:

```
public p5() {
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {

            lblA.setText("Hello Java"); // Error is here
        }
    });
    final JLabel lblA = new JLabel("New label");
    lblA.setBounds(91, 68, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblA);
```

Comment: please post a SSCCE to receive better help for your problem. Read more about it here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: That error message suggests to me that you have code that's not inside a method or something. Post the code you are using (create an SSCCE as suggested in the other comment that demonstrates exactly what you are doing)

Comment: .. 2) `lblA.setBounds(91, 68, 46, 14);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place

```java
final JLabel lblA = new JLabel("New label");
```

before

```java
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {

        lblA.setText("Hello Java"); // Error is here
    }
});
```

not after it and your syntax error should go away.